# Is moving IAB purchases between apps possible?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I *have 3 apps, that im now looking to merge into single one.* Each app had its own set of IAB items. The new merged app will have all the IAB items aswell, however **is it possible to tell if user has purchased given IAB item in the previous app so I can enable it in the new merge-app without paying again?** Im looking for a solution different than handling sending the data to my own server, and downloading it in the new app etc. Ideally Google Play internally. Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible?

No, You have to handle this with the help of your server. Google does not take care of what items you have bought from other app, if same item is available in different app then it would be consider a new different.

Simply, I guess that you have information of users who have bought items from your 3 apps, you can call web service, if user had bought then give all services to user otherwise ask for to pay.

Answer (score 0):

Each app has its own product list. You cannot sell items that appear on another app's product list.

Google is not provding any way to do so.